# leaflet geocoding with input box

Tags: javascript, geocoding, leaflet

I'm coding a website which is using bootstrap. I have a leaflet map on it. I must use geocoding and reverse geocoding. I try [this](https://github.com/smeijer/L.GeoSearch) plugin but i have some problems.

**1 - I want to use a searchbox which is not on the map.**

I have an input box which is in the diffrent div from map's div. This plugin adds a map control to search adresses. How can i use my input box to search adresses? Maybe i must use only a provider not a plugin for geocoding. But how?

**2 - Marker's latlng for reverse geocoding**

I have a marker which is draggable. When i stop dragging the marker, I want to get adress from marker's latlng.

So, I want a geocoding provider which is free to do all of this. Or modify plugin for my purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should use the providers directly if you do not want to use the control's own input and other features. Each provider has a method called `GetLocations`, which takes two arguments:

- `qry`: string containing the search query
- `callback`: a function that will be called when the results are available from the provider. This function should take an array of results as its single argument

From the looks of it, each provider result will contain:

- X: longitude
- Y: latitude
- Label: name

I haven't worked with this plugin myself, but it's very similar to how my own geocoding plugin, [Leaflet Control Geocoder](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-control-geocoder), works.

Leaflet Control Geocoder also has the functionality you request in your other question: each provider  has a method called `reverse`, which takes a `LatLng` as argument instead of a string query. From a quick look, it appears GeoSearch doesn't have that functionality, but I might just have missed it.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there a tutorial you know to write my own provider plugin?

Comment: @RasimAndıran not really a tutorial, but the `IGeocoder` interface is documented here: https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-control-geocoder#igeocoder. You can also have a look at for example the Google geocoder implementation, which is sort of straight forward: https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-control-geocoder/blob/master/Control.Geocoder.js#L660